# Removing a set string from each line while the file is being read

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, replace

I have a .txt file that pulls a list of users by a powershell script that I cant edit. When the list of users is created it comes back as such:

```
"Scott Smith","user"
"Tom Smith","user"
"Paul Smith","user"
```

I tried to do a replace

```
s = set()

with open('OldUserList.txt') as f:
     for line in f:
        s.add(line)


list2 = open('NewUserList.txt', 'r+')

for ii in list2:
   if ii not in s:
      list2.write(ii.strip("\n")+" ***\n")
      replace('","user"','')
```

What I get back is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\readlist.py", line 13, in <module>
    replace('","user"","')
NameError: name 'replace' is not defined
```

I was wondering what is supposed to be used for `.replace`? I have seen this used multiple times in manuals and in examples I saw on this site. Any advice on this or better ways of writing this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `"Scott Smith"'"user"` was this a typo and suppose to be `"Scott Smith","user"`?

Comment: @MooingRawr yes, sorry that was my fault

Answer (score 3):

The method is `string.replace(old, new)`, so for your case it would be:

```
for ii in list2:
   if ii not in s:
      list2.write((ii.strip("\n")+" ***\n").replace('","user"', ''))
```

Comment: this does not work as it marks all the users in NewUserList as a new user even though they are in the old list they are marked as if they are not :/

Comment: So you want to remove ","user"" from the string?

Comment: yes, I am thinking I need to do this in a separate function to run before the compare happens so it does not flag falsely

Comment: I updated the code above, try that and see if it does the trick.

Comment: this did remove the string but it is flagging every line as a new user.

Comment: It's flagging every line as a new user because you are checking to see if the string `"Scott Smith","user"` is already in the list as opposed to checking to see if `'"Scott Smith"'` is in the list. What you need to do is correctly format string prior to checking if it's in the other list.